# Separate and Manipulate Rows by Rule

Tags: r, string

I have a DF:

```
1 119629-19
2 3,750 TL
3 70383-4024
4 48256-550
5 1,300 TL
6 9842-4913
7 104146-243
8 63839-1196
9 1,500 TL
10 1718-1974
11 1718-1973
12 119808-7
13 3,000 TL
14 2957-714
15 5,500 TL
16 117842-24
17 1718-1948
18 1718-1949
19 1718-1760
20 1718-1966
21 1718-1801
22 1718-1829
23 119257-4
24 119257-1
```

As you can see, numeric lines are ID and others are Price. Every price is the price of the upper ID's price.

I want to create a DF as:

```
ID             Price
119629-19   3,750 TL
70383-4024  NULL
48356-550   1,300 TL
9842-4913   NULL
104146-243  NULL
63839-1196  1,500 TL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a vector of mixed IDs and prices

```
library(tidyverse)

mixed <- c('119629-19','3,750 TL','70383-4024','48256-550','1,300 TL','9842-4913','104146-243','63839-1196','1,500 TL')
```

Create two columns: an `id` column and a `price` column which is just offset by one

```
df <- tibble(
  id = mixed,
  price = lead(mixed)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   id         price     
#>   <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1 119629-19  3,750 TL  
#> 2 3,750 TL   70383-4024
#> 3 70383-4024 48256-550 
#> 4 48256-550  1,300 TL  
#> 5 1,300 TL   9842-4913 
#> 6 9842-4913  104146-243
#> 7 104146-243 63839-1196
#> 8 63839-1196 1,500 TL  
#> 9 1,500 TL   <NA>
```

Keeping only the rows where `id` contains a dash and replacing the non-prices with `NA` yields the desired result.

```
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(id, "-")) %>%
  mutate(price = ifelse(str_detect(price, "-"), NA, price))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   id         price   
#>   <chr>      <chr>   
#> 1 119629-19  3,750 TL
#> 2 70383-4024 <NA>    
#> 3 48256-550  1,300 TL
#> 4 9842-4913  <NA>    
#> 5 104146-243 <NA>    
#> 6 63839-1196 1,500 TL
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot put NULL into data frames. When you miss a number, you should fill it with NA's.

```
data = c('119629-19', '3,750 TL', '70383-4024', '48256-550',
         '1,300 TL', '9842-4913', '104146-243', '63839-1196',
         '1,500 TL', '1718-1974', '1718-1973', '119808-7',
         '3,000 TL', '2957-714', '5,500 TL', '117842-24',
         '1718-1948', '1718-1949', '1718-1760', '1718-1966',
         '1718-1801', '1718-1829', '119257-4', '119257-1')

new_data = list()
for (i in seq_along(data)) {
  if (grepl('TL', data[i])) {
    new_data[[i]] = data.frame(ID = data[i-1], Price = data[i])
  } else if (grepl('TL', data[i+1])) {
    new_data[[i]] = NULL
  } else {
    new_data[[i]] = data.frame(ID = data[i], Price = NA)
  }
}
new_data = dplyr::bind_rows(new_data)
```